# ArrayList.remove() is not removing an object

Tags: java, arraylist

I know this is a messy implementation, but I basically have this code (I wrote all of it), and I need to be able to remove a student or instructor from the list when using the appropriate menu choice. Everything else in the code works, just not menu options 3 and 4. I'm entering the exact same information for the object when trying to delete. Here's the code. All three classes are below.

Driver class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Driver {
private ArrayList<Student> students;
private ArrayList<Instructor> instructors;

public static void main(String[] args) {        
    Driver aDriver = new Driver();
    aDriver.run();      
}

public Driver() {
    students = new ArrayList<Student>();
    instructors = new ArrayList<Instructor>();
}

private void run() {
    Student aStudent;
    Instructor anInstructor;
    Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice = -1;
    String str = "Enter a menu option:\n";

    str += " 0: Quit\n";
    str += " 1: Add new student\n";
    str += " 2: Add new instructor\n";
    str += " 3: Delete existing student\n";
    str += " 4: Delete existing instructor\n";
    str += " 5: Print list of students\n";
    str += " 6: Print list of instructors\n";
    str += "Your choice: ";

    do {
        System.out.print(str);
        choice = inp.nextInt();

        switch(choice) {
        case 0:
            System.out.println("Thanks! Have a great day!");
            break;
        case 1:
            aStudent = getStudentInfo();
            addStudent(aStudent);
            break;
        case 2:
            anInstructor = getInstructorInfo();
            addInstructor(anInstructor);
            break;
        case 3:
            aStudent = getStudentInfo();
            deleteStudent(aStudent);
            break;
        case 4:
            anInstructor = getInstructorInfo();
            deleteInstructor(anInstructor);
            break;
        case 5:
            printStudents();
            break;
        case 6:
            printInstructors();
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid menu item " + choice);  
        }
    }
    while(choice != 0);
}

public Student getStudentInfo() {
    Student aStudent;
    String name = null;
    String id = null;
    double GPA = 0.0;
    Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("\n\nEnter the student's name: ");
    name = inp.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter the student's ID: ");
    id = inp.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter the student's GPA: ");
    GPA = inp.nextDouble();

    aStudent = new Student(name, id, GPA);
    return aStudent;
}

public Instructor getInstructorInfo() {
    Instructor anInstructor;
    String name = null;
    String id = null;
    String dept = null;
    String email = null;
    Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("\n\nEnter the instructor's name: ");
    name = inp.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter the instructor's ID: ");
    id = inp.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter the instructor's department: ");
    dept = inp.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter the instructor's email address: ");
    email = inp.nextLine();

    anInstructor = new Instructor(name, id, dept, email);
    return anInstructor;
}

public void addStudent(Student aStudent) {
    students.add(aStudent);
}

public void addInstructor(Instructor anInstructor) {
    instructors.add(anInstructor);
}

public void deleteStudent(Student aStudent) {
    students.remove(aStudent);
}

public void deleteInstructor(Instructor anInstructor) {
    instructors.remove(anInstructor);
}

public void printStudents() {
    System.out.println("\n\n" + Student.printHeader());

    for(int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++) {
        System.out.print(students.get(i));
    }

    System.out.print("\n\n");
}

public void printInstructors() {
    System.out.print("\n\n" + Instructor.printHeader());

    for(int i = 0; i < instructors.size(); i++) {
        System.out.print(instructors.get(i));
    }

    System.out.print("\n\n");
}
}
```

Student class:

```
public class Student {
private String name;
private String id;   //String to allow for the possibility of leading zeroes
private double GPA;

public Student() {
    name = "TestFirst TestLast";
    id = "00000";
    GPA = -1.00;
}

public Student(String name1, String id1, double GPA1) {
    name = name1;
    id = id1;
    GPA = GPA1;
}

public static String printHeader() {
    String str = String.format("%-25s%-7s%-6s\n", "Name", "ID", "GPA");
    return str;
}

public String toString() {
    String str = String.format("%-25s%-7s%-6.3f\n", name, id, GPA);
    return str;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setGPA(double GPA2) {
    GPA = GPA2;
}
}
```

Instructor class:

```
public class Instructor {
private String name;
private String id;
private String dept;
private String email;

public Instructor() {
    name = "TestFirst TestLast";
    id = "-00001";
    dept = "TestDept";
    email = "test@test.net";
}

public Instructor(String name1, String id1, String dept1, String email1) {
    name = name1;
    id = id1;
    dept = dept1;
    email = email1;
}

public static String printHeader() {
    String str = String.format("%-30s%-6s%-15s%-15s\n", "Name", "ID", "Department", "Email Address");
    return str;
}

public String toString() {
    String str = String.format("%-30s%-6s%-15s%-15s\n", name, id, dept, email);
    return str;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You must correctly override the `equals()` method for both `Student` and `Instructor` classes.

When overriding equals, it is good to override `hashCode()` as well.
new Student(name, id, GPA);

For example, something like this:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
  if (!(o instanceof Student)) {
    return false;
  }
  Student other = (Student) o;
  return name.equals(other.name) && id.equals(other.id) && GPA == other.GPA;
}

public int hashCode() {
  return name.hashCode();
}
```

This way, you give a chance to the `ArrayList` figure out which object correspond to the one you passed as a parameter when deleting. If you don't override the above methods, it will use the default implementations in `Object`, which compare memory addresses which are definitely different as you remove a new `Student` object.

You can read even more information about the 2 methods in the javadocs for `Object`.

Comment: Isn't the hashCode going to give issues when different students with the same name exist?

Comment: No, because the hashCode() goal is to separate instances into buckets. Only instances in the same bucket are compared using equals. So, students with the same name should go into the same bucket.

Comment: Have you seen my updated answer? There is code that you can copy and paste in there.

Comment: Be that as it may, a better override of hashCode would probably take id into account either instead of or in addition to the name. Fewer conflicts would occur (assuming that student id is unique).

Comment: I pasted your code and it worked. I'd like to make sure I understand, however, if you wouldn't mind verifying for me.

The `Object o` parameter is a placeholder that will accept any `Object` passed to it. The if statement checks that it is an object of the appropriate type (in this case `Student`, but in the `Instructor` class it would be `Instructor`), and returns false if the object isn't of that type.

The line `Student other ...` simply places the `Object` into a `Student` object so that it can be compared, and the final statement actually checks for the above to be equal. Correct?

Comment: Correct so far. These methods are called internally by the ArrayList when trying to figure out which object to remove.

Comment: Just a as a side note: If you use Eclipse you can right-click in your object's class -> `Source` -> `Generate hashCode() and equals()...`

Answer (score 9):

You need to Override equals and hashcode methods for collections to work properly.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (!(obj instanceof Student))
        return false;
    Student other = (Student) obj;
    return id == null ? false : id.equals(other.id);//Compare Id if null falseF
}
```

Since you are only using ArrayList there is hashcode method will not be used but it is still good practice to provide it.

```
 @Override
public int hashCode() {
    return id == null ? 0 : id.hashCode();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You didn't override the method [`equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) for `Student` and `Instructor`.

This method is used by the `ArrayList` to check wether 2 objects are the same. Without a custom implementation it will just check references, which will be different in your case since they are two different objects.

To provide custom equality you will have to check all the fields of the involved classes to be the same. This can be done recursively by calling `equals` on instance variables.

Comment: Okay, I get what you're saying, but I'm not sure how to implement it. When I override `toString`, for example, all I need to do is return a `String` object from the method. When I override `equals`, I need to use an if statement to compare, but what two things do I compare, especially when using `ArrayList.remove()`? `remove()` takes an object in, but how do I compare?

Comment: The `equals` method is called by the `ArrayList` itself. You just need to implement the method such that it will return `true` if and only if two students are the same student (this may mean if they have the same name and the same whatever you need)

Answer (score 3):

Overriding the equals method of Student and Instructor will work:

Here is an example for the Student class:

```
public boolean equals(Object other){
    if(other == null) return false;
    if(other == this) return true;
    if(!(other instanceof Student)) return false;
    Student otherStudent = (Student)other;
    return otherStudent.id.equals(this.id);
}
```

You may also want to override `hashCode()`:

```
public String hashCode(){
    return new HashCodeBuilder(17, 31).
        append(name).
        append(id).
        toHashCode();
}
```