# ArrayList.remove(Object o) not iterating over contents

Tags: java, arraylist

So, I've been sitting on this problem for several hours now and I'm out of ideas. I looked through the documentation (ArrayList and Object) and read a lot of Stackoverflow questions regarding `ArrayList.remove(Object obj)`, but nothing helped.

I try to implement a simulation (game?) where I have a Cell[][] to store the map. Each Cell has inhabitants (class Person) stored in an ArrayList, which move one step every iteration. When a Person moves I add them to the next Cell and remove them from the old one. Or rather try, as the remove part doesn't work yet.

My Question: I need help implementing the ArrayList.remove(Object obj) method.
What I got so far:

```
class Cell
{
    private final int x;
    private final int y;
    ArrayList<Person> inhabs = new ArrayList<Person>();

    /** this method is called by a Person that wants to move to another Cell **/
    public void moveMe(Person p){
        try{
            Cell northOfHere = grid.grid[y-1][x]//direction will be changed to be random
            northOfHere.add(p);
        }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex){/*person falls from the edge of the world*/}

        inhabs.remove(p); //this is not working right
    }

    public void add(Person p){
        inhabs.add(p);
    }
}
```

Class Person:

```
class Person extends Object
{
    private int health;
    private int strength;
    private int food;
    private final int nation;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj){
        if(obj == null){return false;}
        if(obj == this){return true;}
        if(!(obj instanceof Person)){return false;}

        Person p = (Person)obj;
        return p.toString().equals(toString());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(){
        return toString().hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return String.format("Health: %03d, Strength: %03d, Food: %03d, Nation: %02d", health, strength, food, nation);
    }
}
```

Some key points:

- The `inhabs.remove(p);` is not working <strike>right</strike> how I want it.
- It does work in the first iteration, but in the second it only returns `false`.
- The first iteration over the `Person.equals(Object obj)` by the ArrayList always returns true because of the line `if(obj == this){return true;}`.
- On the second iteration it never even starts to compare the objects (?!?).
- The ArrayList is not empty.

I understand that this is a very specific question, however I could not find anything that adressed the problem of the ArrayList not even going over the Elements in it.

edit: more Code. Probably irrelevant to the problem, but i'll post it anyway, for context.

```
class Grid{        
    Cell[][] grid;

    public Grid(Cell[][] in){
        grid = in; //has some cells with people in it.
    }

    //simply iterates over all cells
    public void tick(){
        for(int y = 0; y<grid.length; y++){
            for(int x = 0; x<grid[y].length; x++){
                grid[y][x].tick();
            }
        }
}


class Cell
{
    Grid grid;

    public Cell(/*some constants constants*/ Grid g, ArrayList<Person> inh){
        grid = g;
        if(inh == null){
            inhabs = new ArrayList<Person>();
        }else{
            inhabs = inh;
        }
    }

    //tells every person to make a step
    public void tick(){
        for(Person p : inhabs.toArray(new Person[inhabs.size()])){
            p.tick();
        }
    }

    //and all the other methods from above, of course
}


class Person extends Object
{
    Cell cell;

    public Person(Cell c, int h, int s, int f, int n){
        cell = c;
        health = h;
        strength = s;
        food = f;
        nation = n;
    }

    public void tick(){
        //for testing, later more options
        cell.moveMe(this);
    }

    //and all the other methods from above, of course
}
```

Comment: "I need help implementing the ArrayList.remove(Object obj) method." No you don't: the implementation that's in `java.util.ArrayList` is just fine. Your problem must be in your `equals` method, because that's how `ArrayList.remove` [works](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.remove%28java.lang.Object%29).

Comment: You are technically correct, the best kind of correct. I need help getting it to work correctly. 
The problem is probably in the `equals` method, however the ArrayList doesn't call that method even once in the second iteration.

Comment: What is the exact error log?

Comment: @Turunambartanen you mention "iteration" in your question, but there's no iteration here - what are you referring to?

Comment: +Debanik DawnI don't have an Error. the ArrayList simply doesn't iterate over the `equals` method of it's contents. The only Error, if you will, is that `ArrayList.remove` returns false without calling a singe `equals` method on its contents

Comment: make sure that the `toString()` method returns the same thing. Debug the `equals` method. It would be better, IMO, to compare the instance fiels values instead of using the `toString` method.

Comment: Do show your entire code. Where are you calling these functions from?

Comment: @Andy Turner the iterations are done by the Grid class (irrelevenat to the problem). It just iterates over the `Cell[][]`, the Cells iterate over the ArrayList (this works) and the Persons then move by calling the cell they belong to `cell.moveMe(this);`

Comment: You definitely have two "people" with same `health, strength, food, nation`. You chose object identity poorly. Also, comparing result of `toString()` and hashing result of `toString()` is way more work that it could be.

Comment: Either your ArrayList is empty (can't know without seeing the code where you actually add) or there are bugs in the toString() method where the variables aren't initialized properly. Why don't you use a constructor?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of this. For me, your class is working fine in a `List`

Comment: ok, be right back. trying to make a MVCE that can show the problem.

Comment: Is it a multi-threaded app?

Comment: @Tamas Rev no, not multiThreaded

Comment: Okay, then states are always consistent. I don't know than, maybe that actual person wasn't in the `inhabs` list anyway.

Comment: MVCE:
https://github.com/Turun/StackoverflowMVCE
main class wil instantiate a Grid instance an then tick/iterate 4 times.
Text on console for cheap logging. `removed: false` with out any other text means that the ArrayList did not remove anything but didn't call the equals method either.

Comment: You should [edit] the question with your MCVE instaed of using external sites.

Comment: Also, while you do that, make the example minimal. All you need is a list and objects to test for removal. We don't need 4 classes with 10 methods.

Comment: @Turunambartanen If you check [my answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46115121/4391450), this is a [mcve], I just didn't add the `Person` class (taken from your question). But I have a list, add a few, remove a few, and show the result (in comment in my case). Try to do something similar, so we don't need the `Cell`, `Grid`, ...

Comment: @AxelH I know how an ArrayList works. "Use as little code as possible **that still produces the same problem**" I posted it with as few lines of Code as I thought are needed. My second post on this site will surely be more professional.
I just hoped someone would spot a stupid error in my code. From further testing it seems that i do loose my ArrayList somewhere.

Comment: Someone *will* find the error in your code if you just [edit] your post with the minimal code that people don't need to jump through hoops for.

Comment: @Turunambartanen I still don't see an [mcve] in your question. You've posted a github (not really the way of SO...) including your full code ... read my edit ... next time, use a schema to draw your method path ...

Comment: @AxelH
Yes, I looked for a few more hours, even wrote my own ArrayList and still couldn't solve the problem. 
Your solution is spot on. I accepted it as the correct one. Next time I will make sure to get a MCVE before I post and put it in my question. And I should probably start using schemata instead of winging it all the time. 
Thanks for taking your time and solving that problem for me. I had already given up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't be reproduced, here is a small test with your logic :

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Person p1 = new Person(10, 2, 2, 1);
    Person p2 = new Person(10, 2, 2, 2);
    Person p3 = new Person(10, 2, 2, 3);

    List<Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>();
    list.add(p1);
    list.add(p2);
    list.add(p3);

    System.out.println(list.remove(p2)); //true
    System.out.println(list.remove(p2)); //false
    System.out.println(list.remove( new Person(10, 2, 2, 3))); //true
}
```

My guess is that you don't use the correct `Person`, you either construct a new instance without giving every variables correctly. (Note that you didn't provide the constructor here, with a `final` value, this can't work...)

---

I have read your code. Your problem is simple.

You `tick` a `Cell` that will `tick` every `Person` in that `Cell`. From there you move that `Person` from the current `Cell` using `Cell.moveMe(Person p);`. You do move the instance in the new `Cell.inhabs` and remove it from the current one. **BUT** since you have references of all your instance in both way, your `Person` is never instructed to which `Cell` it is moved ... so when you call :

```
public void tick(){
    //for testing
    cell.moveMe(this);
}
```

`cell` is still the initial position... but that `cell` don't hold that person, so it can't remove the instance received.

A simple correction would be to return the cell where you move him into :

```
public Cell moveMe(Person p){
    Cell northOfHere = null;
    try{
        northOfHere = grid.grid[y-1][x];
        northOfHere.add(p);
    }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex){
        System.out.println("fell from edge");/*person falls from the edge of the world*/
    }
    System.out.format("Remove from %s person %s%n", this, p);
    System.out.println("removed: " + inhabs.remove(p));
    return northOfHere;
}
```

And update that cell :

```
public void tick(){
    //for testing
    cell = cell.moveMe(this);
}
```

I agreed here to keep `cell` to `null` when he "feel off the map", as it remain outside of any cell.

Comment: "with a final value, this can't work" could you expand? what doesn't work? the remove method? why?

Comment: @Turunambartanen No, just the fact that you didn't provide a constructor ... for me this works fine...

Answer (score 0):

As Andy Turner pointed out, you need to fix the `equals()` method. In `Person` class the `equals()` must be precise.

There is a [contract](https://www.programcreek.com/2011/07/java-equals-and-hashcode-contract/) between `hashCode()` and `equals()`: if one object equals another, then their `hashCode()` must be the same. So the easiest way is to piggyback `equals()` too on `toString()`:

```
class Person // automatically extends Object
{

    // ...
    @Override

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return (obj instanceof Person) && // instanceof is null-safe
            this.toString().equals((Person) obj).toString();
    }
}
```

Honestly, I don't like ***writing*** `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods, unless absolutely necessary. They are cumbersome and error-prone. In this case, it doesn't look absolutely necessary. There are a few alternatives:

- generate them with your IDE
- use apache `EqualsBuilder` and `HashCodeBuilder`. [Here](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2072488/apache-commons-equalsbuilder-and-hashcodebuilder.html) is a nice example.

With `HashCodeBuilder` you'd write code like this:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
   return new HashCodeBuilder()
      .append(this.health)
      .append(this.strength)
      ...
      .toHashCode();
}
```

With `EqualsBuilder` you'd write code like this:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
      if (obj instanceof Person == false)
      {
        return false;
      }
      if (this == obj)
      {
         return true;
      }

      Person that = (Person) obj;
      return new EqualsBuilder()
        .append(this.health, that.health)
        .append(this.strength, that.strength)
        ...
        .isEquals();
}
```

Comment: "_In Person class the equals() isn't overridden_" yes it is ... might be updated will you were writing your answer.

Comment: Aw, indeed. I realized later that it was overridden, but forgot to edit this part of the text. Updating...

Comment: PS : Didn't knew apache `EqualsBuilder`, but what is the difference, you still need to list every argument for both instance, so the method look the same (in a more verbose/readable way).

Comment: It's better to mark the question as duplicate than to give yet another "override equals" answer of which there are enough of because this is a basic problem which was met by many people ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12697407/arraylist-remove-is-not-removing-an-object)). Also just use Lombok's `@EqualsAndHashCode` to generatethe methods.

Comment: It has a few minor advantages. 1. It'll always work fine with `HashCodeBuilder`. 2. It'll deal with the possibly null references for you. The `Person` class has only primitives, but other classes can contain references, which might be null.

Comment: @user1803551 I read that question, I did override the equals method. The problem is the Arraylist doesn't call the equals method on any of the objects in it.

Comment: @TamasRev FYI, there was a mistake in his code using "bidirectional relationships (1----->0-N)", one of the relationships was not updated, the one that hold the list...